# ¿se puede modifcar una clave primaria en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta sobre mysql, actualmente tengo dos tablas usuarios donde mi clave principal es el **dni** y en sesion. **id** y tengo un formulario desde php en el cual actualizo los datos de una persona.. mi consulta es la siguiente:

¿yo puedo atualizar los datos de mi clave principal de usuarios? en este caso es el dni de usuario...

hice esta consulta en sql y me cambia todos los datos, pero cuando quiero modificar el dni( la cedula) se queda siempre con la misma. Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

```
`$sql = "UPDATE usuarios u JOIN sesion s SET u.cedula='$cedula', u.nombres='$nombres', u.apellidos='$apellidos', u.telefono='$telefono', u.direccion='$direccion', s.correo='$correo', s.usuario='$usuario'  WHERE s.usuarios_cedula='$cedula' &&  u.cedula='$cedula'";`
```

Comment: no deberias utilizar un dato que se pueda modificar como clave principal. aparte de eso, la mayoria de las bases no lo permiten.

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta corta es **SI SE PUEDE.**

La respuesta larga es, tu implementación puede traer varios problemas; debes tener cuidado con los updates que utilizan `JOIN`. También recuerda que las llaves primarias son únicas; no puedes repetirlas.

Mi recomendación es cambiar la estructura de tu base de datos un poco para que puedas usar [llaves foraneas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

De esta manera puedes hacer un update a tu "tabla padre" que podría ser `usuarios` y los cambios se harían en cascada hacia las "tablas hijas"

Considera la creación de las llaves foraneas:

```
ALTER TABLE `sesion` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`cedula`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Entonces el siguiente query actualizaría la tabla usuarios y la tabla sesión.

```
UPDATE usuarios SET cedula='$cedula_nueva', nombres='$nombres', apellidos='$apellidos', telefono='$telefono', direccion='$direccion' WHERE u.cedula='$cedula_anterior';
```

Y finalmente podrías ejecutar el siguiente query inmediatamente después en tu script PHP:

```
UPDATE sesion SET correo='$correo', usuario='$usuario' WHERE usuarios_cedula='$cedula_anterior';
```

Comment: Aquí ya te contestaron de que se puede se puede, pero al menos para mi, no es recomendable hacerlo y aquí te están dando una buena alternativa, suerte.